# Solving alphabetical expression to obtain sentences using Binary Tree

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, binary-tree, binary-search-tree, graph-algorithm

I'm trying to solve alphabetical expressions to obtain valid sentences.

Example of input and output would be:-

#### Input

Actual:

```
(((​"​one​"​ . ​"​two​"​) | ​"​twelve​"​) . (​"​zero​"​ | ​"​o​"​) . ​"​six​"​)
```

Tokenized:

```
['(', '(', '(', 'one', '.', 'two', ')', '|', 'twelve', ')', '.', 
 '(', 'zero', '|', 'o', ')', '.', 'six', ')']
```

#### Output

- one two zero six
- one two o six
- twelve o six

#### Operators

- `()` - *required* grouping operator
- `[]` - *optional* grouping operator
- `.` - *concatenate* connecting operator
- `|` - *OR* connecting operator

***The `.` operator does have a higher precedence than the `|` operator.
I am not able to understand how should I go about it. (I want to write the code in Python)***

Comment: In your input, each double quote is surrounded by [zero-width spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_space). Is this intended?

Comment: You'll need to write a tokenizer and a (probably recursive descent) parser. Too broad for an SO question.

Comment: I suppose "twelve zero six" would also be a possible outcome.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you already managed to tokenise the input. I would then suggest as a second step to build a tree from the tokens, so that the following input:

```
(((​"​one​"​ . ​"​two​"​) | ​"​twelve​"​) . (​"​zero​"​ | ​"​o​"​) . ​"​six​"​)
```

...would become the following tree:

[image]

Note that you could implement the optional words (wrapped in `[...]`) re-using the OR operator in combination with a `None` element (which would produce nothing in a final string). For instance `["six"]` would be interpreted as if it were `(None|"six")`, which in the tree would be:

[image]

With the tree you can use recursion to find the possible strings. Each recursive call would return a list of possible strings (maybe just one). In case the children belong to a `.` (AND) operation, then all lists of strings found for the children must be combined as a Cartesian product. In case they belong to a `|` (OR) operation, these lists should be just concatenated (since all possible strings for any of the children are possible for the parent).

Here is some code that could be useful:

```py
import itertools
import re

# subclass list just to distinguish between arguments of a "." or "|" operator
class OrList(list): # for "|" operator arguments
    pass

class AndList(list): # for "." operator arguments
    pass

def parse(tokens):
    # helper function to conditionally either append-to or extend a list
    def add(lst, factor):
        if type(factor) == type(lst):
            lst.extend(factor)
        else:
            lst.append(factor)
        return lst

    # helper function to conditionally return the given list or its only element
    def simplify(lst):
        if isinstance(lst, OrList): # remove duplicates
            for i in range(len(lst)-1,-1,-1):
                if lst.index(lst[i]) < i:
                    del lst[i]
        return lst if len(lst) > 1 else lst[0]

    it = iter(tokens + [""])

    def recur(end):
        terms = OrList()
        factors = AndList()
        token = None
        while token != end:
            token = next(it)
            if token[0] == '"':
                add(factors, token[1:-1]) # remove the quotes
            elif token == "(":
                add(factors, recur(")"))
            elif token == "[": # encode [expr] as if it were: (|expr)
                add(factors, add(OrList([None]), recur("]")))
            else:
                raise ValueError("Expected expression, got {}".format(token))
            token = next(it)
            if token != end and token not in ".|":
                raise ValueError("Expected operator, got {}".format(token))
            if token == "|" or token == end:
                add(terms, simplify(factors))
                factors = AndList()
        return simplify(terms)

    return recur("")

def validPhrases(node): # returns list of strings
    if isinstance(node, list):
        results = [validPhrases(child) for child in node]
        if isinstance(node, OrList):
            # flatten
            results = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(results))
        else: # instance of AndList
            # all combinations
            results = [" ".join([s for s in combi if s != None]) 
                    for combi in itertools.product(*results)]
        return list(set(results)) # remove duplicates
    else: # str
        return [node]

def generate(expr):
    # tokenize
    tokens = re.findall(r'"[^"]*"|\S', expr) # don't throw away the quotes yet
    # make a tree in line with precedence rules
    tree = parse(tokens)
    # finally build all possible strings from this tree
    return validPhrases(tree)

expr = '((("one" . "two" | "twelve") . ("zero" | "o")) . "six")'

print(generate(expr))
```

See it run on [repl.it](https://repl.it/@trincottrincots/ProduceAllMatchesForRegularExpression)